# Properties with mutual calculation dependency, like a vector and their polar prepresentation

Tags: c#, wpf

My question is quite simple to explain: There is some way (elegant if possible) to have mutual dependency (and calculations) under MVVM using wpf?, I have a datagrid where you define vectors (x, y, z) and for the other hand their polar representation (two angles a, b and lenght) both (vector and polar) have  mutual dependency, if the user edit one, the other have to be calculated and vice versa. My problem is the a circular Notify property changed events

Comment: In your viewmodels (or models), represent your vector only in one form through only one property, for example the cartesian form. If you need to present it in polar form somewhere in your UI, use bindings with a custom value converter (based on `IValueConverter`) which converts the bound vector from the cartesian form to the polar form and back. By the way, "DependencyProperties" tag does not seem to apply to your problem. "DependencyProperties" are not a short-hand for any properties that depend in some way on another property, DP's are distinctly different from normal .NET properties.

Comment: If i understand tye scenario correctly. I woukd consider an action that does all the calculations and sets the private backers of all properties. It then raises propertychanged on all by calling the vm method with strings. Call that indirectly from the setter of all involved properties. You don't want to call it more than once when you initially build your vm so have a method the setters call and that calls an action which does nothing initially. Set it to your action that does stuff at the end of the ctor or after your vm's properties are initially set.